# Ant: How to start the web server and then return and run unit tests?

Tags: ant, junit

I have an Ant file contains a Junit target, before running the Junit target i have to start the web server(also a target) to let the Unit test run smoothly(there are some web based UI unit tests). However when i start the web server, the ant script is pending and block all following execution. Is there a way to start the web server and then return and running the Unit tests?

```
    <target name="runserver" description="Run hosted mode">
       <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">.....</java>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="runserver">
       <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes" haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true">...</junit>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have to use "spawn=true" in your exec/java Task. Otherwise after the server has started as a forked process, Ant will be suspended because it tries to read from the standard input. Try in your exec task something like:

```
    <exec executable="${your.Server.executable}" spawn="true"/>
    <java jar="${your.Server.jar}" spawn="true">...</java>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how to wrap my <java> task in the exec? see above, the <java> task takes the 'classpath' as one of its attributes.

Comment: Hi, the java task also accepts the "spawn=true" attribute (it's false by default). So it should become <java failonerror="true" spawn="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">.....</java>

Comment: i did but the Ant console said "spawn does not allow attributes related to input, output, error, result
spawn also does not allow timeout
finally, spawn is not compatible with a nested I/O <redirector>"

Comment: Maybe you can try to use an [Ant Exec Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) directly on the "gwt-dev.jar". Otherwise you can just include 1 more step in your testing process #ensure web-server is running

Comment: I wrap the start server command as a bat file and call it like this:<exec executable="../test/startserver.bat" spawn="true"></exec>, it works, thank you.